# The formatting of HTML page is lost when viewed as an email in outlook

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I have a simple html page with "Lato" font used in it. First of all, the page works fine in browsers. But when I view it on Microsoft outlook (any version), the header loses its formatting (the logo and paragraph get misaligned), and the font does not work as well. It always displays as 'serif' font. I tried many exercises like using @font-face etc. But nothing seemed to work. Also, I tried positioning the header components(for proper display in outlook) but the original alignment(in browsers) gets distorted. So how can I keep the font that I want to use to work in outlook as well? And is there any way to workout the header so that it does not loose its formatting?
Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

The fact is that Outlook uses Word as an email editor (not IE). You can read about supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338200(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: I don't know why this question is downvoted.
I had issues with the border color of td elements and eventually found a solution. So, can you atleast tell me how to apply an external (google) font to work in outlook as well?

Comment: I've gone through the links that you provided and it clearly states that font-family attribute is supported in Word. Any further help?